# Axios keeps making https calls when I use an http url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, axios

I am having trouble using an API as it keeps making an https call and not an http call. The https call is behind a paywall and the free version of the api only supports http calls. I am using https://weatherstack.com/ API.
I am using react with the axios package to make my HTTP calls.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const Weather = (props) => {
    const [response, setResponse] = useState([])

    const hook = () => {
        axios
            .get(`http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&query=${props.country.capital}`)
            .then(response => {
                console.log('promise fulfilled')
                setResponse(response.data)
                
            })

    }

    useEffect(hook, [])
    
    console.log(response)
    return (
        <div>Temperature: {} </div>)
}

export default Weather
```

The error message I receive from the API is this

```
info: "Access Restricted - Your current Subscription Plan does not support HTTPS Encryption."
​​
type: "https_access_restricted"
```

The strange thing is about 20% of the time the call works and I can get my data, but it doesn't work most of the time. TIA

Comment: Its not your axios issue. Plz share the whole component code

Comment: ok my post is updated, i don't think it will make a difference